# Have any Jedi survived episodes I through VII

Tags: star-wars, jedi

How many if any Jedi have survived episodes I through VII in starwars? Yoda, Obi-Wan  and many other Jedi died and Luke was born after starwars started.

Comment: @Adamant Although an answer to the other question *could* answer this one, if it happens to mention a Jedi, many valid answers, including the upvoted accepted one, will not address this question. Doesn't really seem useful to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, Luke was supposed to be the only Jedi after Yoda died, so that would make the answer 'no', at least at the movie canon level. What canon level are you looking for?

Comment: Qui Gon developed the Force Ghost (is that the correct name?) technique, and so could be considered to be at least present and aware throughout the saga. I'll admit it's a bit of a long shot.

Comment: Wait till episode VIII namesake, they'll make Ikrit canon as the stuffed animal will sell like hotcakes. (not a serious prediction)